# How bad it is to copy paste my own code blocks?

Tags: php

! Actually, I am learning PHP from last couple of months and now I am in a stage where I can program small things like a simple Login Page in PHP and mySQL or a Contact Form. I have wrote a lot of codeblocks like inserting something into a database or selecting something from a database etc. etc. But, I always copy paste my own code-blocks from previous projects while working on a new one. **So, I want to know whether this tendency is unique to me only or each of the beginner passes through the same phase once during their journey of being a developer?** 
Please bear with me because I know this isn't really a programming question and doesn't worth your time as well. I tried finding out in Google as well but this is a snap of what I found: 
[image: search results for my query]

I mean to say that most of the search results dealt with copy pasting other's code which is not the case of what I am talking about. In order to save time I do copy paste my own code blocks almost everytime. So, **how bad is this behaviour of mine?**
 
I again apologize for not posting a question that is worth your time but I am finding it hard to learn to code by myself without having any mentor nearby ( Actually, I searched for a mentor who could teach PHP before giving it a start all by myself, but I found none in my area ) for clearing my doubts and as such Internet is the thing which I mostly depend upon for learning about anything.

Comment: This question is opinion based as it seeks a discussion thus it is off-topic here

Comment: Please guide me where should I post such types of questions. ?

Comment: What exactly do you propose as an alternative?  Never re-using code you've previously written and always solving the same problems from scratch?  That hardly seems efficient.

Comment: I would say a lot of developers do copy and paste at some point. I however would recommend not copying and pasting in the ctrl+c ctrl+v way. Instead, when you see code you want to try, actually type it out, it will force you to think through it.

Comment: @David Sir, I know it is efficient but I think I am still in a learning phase and I don't know if this is beneficial for me or not?

Comment: Of course I mean that for code that you haven't written before, just unfamiliar new code. Be wary of just copying and pasting blocks of code you don't understand.

Comment: @ryanmattscott Thank you for your kind opinion, Sir.

Comment: @Sanu_012: *"but I think I am still in a learning phase"* - Pro tip: One is *always* learning.

Comment: @David Sir, thanks for your kind and Quick  Pro Tip. Yes, one is learning something his whole life. :)

Comment: They don't call us copy/pasters for nothing. If you are hand typing out everything you do, and all your calls and code... you are coding in a very inefficient manner.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Copying and pasting own codeblocks is not really a bad thing. Thanks 

Answer (score 1):

This question probably belongs on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com but I'll try to give you a decent answer and some guidance.

People re-use their own code all the time.  You do not however want to copy/paste if possible. The issue with copy/paste is when you have something used more than a few times - like a MySQL database connection - and it needs updating.  I'd rather modify one file (or one small group of files) and have all of my webapps fixed/updated than having to modify 2 or 3 database calls in 9 different web apps...

For things that I use everywhere/all the time - talking with our course management systems API, authenticating a user against our LDAP server, connecting to a MySQL database and running queries, processing forms that are emailed, etc - I've built up my own (or coworkers have) sets of functions, classes, etc.  Which I then keep in a single directory, and can include as needed.

If you do this, you want your functions/object methods to be as generic as possible - for example, my MySQL query function takes several arguments - an associative array with connection info (since we have several DB servers based on purpose), a query, and an array of parameters.  It returns an array with a status code, and then appropriate data - the record set result for inserts, the ID of the last insert, the count of rows affected (for delete/update).  This one function handles 50+ queries and connects to 4 different MySQL servers.